# Type error: 'int' object has no attribute. python int(raw_input())

Tags: python, int, typeerror, raw-input, arcpy

I am utilizing python 2.7 and arcpy do do some data management.

I'm trying to create a script to ask the user what year the data is from, for the file paths to be generated.

```
while True:
    try:
        year =  int(raw_input("What state fiscal year is this for (yyyy)? "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Are you daft?!")
        continue
    if year < 2017:
        print("Sorry tool is only compatible with post 2017 files")
    elif year > 2030:
        print("Someone needs to update the script... it's been over a decade since inception!")
    else:
        print("Party on!")
        break
scriptpath = os.getcwd()
```

The next line is where the user input comes into a file path and also the line throwing up the error:

```
    folder = "OARS Raw Data\OARS S_FY{0}".format(year[2:])
Type error: 'int' object has no attribute '__ getitem __'
```

What is causing it to not pull the year value?
I've tried assigning another variable: `year1 = year`
between scriptpath and folder lines, but still got the type error.

I should mention the folder line worked when I assigned year without the while loop. `year = "2018"`

Comment: `year[2:]` triggers the error, because `year` is an integer and doesn't support item access. What did you want to do with it? Perhaps you wanted to to convert the integer to a string first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`year` is an integer, *not a string*. You can't slice integers:

```
>>> year = 2018
>>> year[2:]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Convert the object to a string first, `str(year)[2:]` would work, *or* use integer operations to get just the last two digits:

```
folder = "OARS Raw Data\\OARS S_FY{0:02}".format(year % 100)
```

`year % 100` takes the remainder of year divided by 100; so the last two digits:

```
>>> year % 100
18
```

Note that I updated the string template too, by adding `:02` any integer smaller than 10 still has a leading `0` added:

```
>>> 'year: {0:02}'.format(9)
'year: 09'
```

Answer (score 1):

For using slicing you would need to transform it into a string first(for example):

```
folder = "OARS Raw Data\OARS S_FY{0}".format(str(year)[2:])
```

or just take mod of `100` for last 2 numbers:

```
folder = "OARS Raw Data\OARS S_FY{0}".format(year%100)
```

Comment: The string issue fixed it right up  thanks everyone. I thought it was an issue within the while loop, didn't even know about not being able to split integers.